# React useEffect - Run on Mount Only

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

Recently, I updated an shopping cart Appt to CRA 3 which includes eslint-plugin-react-hooks useEffect . Appropriately, it forces dependencies to the second parameter array in useEffect.

My intention was to run only on mount, so I had used [] previously and it worked as expected, but now it add adds these dependencies and does not run on load. I understand  I could turn off this eslint rule global or individually, but I would rather know the appropriate way to accomplish this in react.

```
const CartItem = ({ inventoryItems, dispatch, item }) => {
  const invItem = inventoryItems.find(invItem => invItem.id === item.id);

  useEffect(() => {
  const setWarnings = (item) => {
    let warnings = [];
    if (item.quantity > invItem.quantity) {
      warnings.push(`Note quantity of requested ${
        item.name
      }s was reduced by ${item.quantity -
        invItem.quantity} due to sold inventory since it was placed in cart.`);
      item.quantity = invItem.quantity;
    }
    if (item.price !== invItem.price) {
      warnings.push(`Note price for ${
        item.name
      } has changed since it was placed in cart (${
        invItem.price > item.price ? "+ " : ""
      } ${formatPrice(invItem.price - item.price)}).`);
      item.price = invItem.price;
    }
  }
  setWarnings(item)
},[invItem.price, invItem.quantity, item])

  return (/* here I will display my item and below it map warnings array */)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using setState for invItem (inventoryItem).

Set state in functional component. Then, you should then be able to remove your dependencies.

```
const [inventoryItem, setInventoryItem] = useState(inventoryItems.find(invItem => invItem.id === item.id))

const setWarnings = (item) => { 
    // .... logic
}

useEffect(() => {
    // ...logic ( or remove it to a higher scope )
    setInventoryItem( item => {
        setWarnings(item)
        // item will = whatever the current value is and you can do your logic
   })
}, []) // I would try and override that rule regardless.
```

Also, what are you doing with setWarnings? its only available inside useEffect. remove the function declaration and just call it like you are.

Did this help and am I missing anything?

checkout useReducer, could be useful: https://testdriven.io/blog/react-hooks-advanced/

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it more, I think it probably renders with warnings on mount but then I reset item quantity and/or price based on inventory related changes in the creation of warnings. This makes logical sense (sell at current invItem price, and don't sell more than in inventory), but also triggera the appropriate rerender as item dependency is changing and quickly clears the reminders. I'll work on it and post back.